# Error parsing source location in yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I am getting the below error while running the Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
[ERROR] Error parsing source location "D:\a\1\drop": Failed to enumerate directory D:\a\1\drop\ with file pattern *. The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
```

yaml code:

```
steps:
     - task: CopyFiles@2
       inputs:
        Contents: 
            test/templates/templatev.json
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

     - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
       displayName: 'Publish ARM Templates: templates'
       inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: drop

    - task: AzureFileCopy@3
           inputs:
              SourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              Destination: 'AzureBlob'
              storage: 'testblob'
              ContainerName: 'testfolder'
              BlobPrefix: '$(Build.BuildId)'
              outputStorageUri: 'testUrl'
```

in the last step, it is not able find the source path.

Comment: Hi @Lakshmi Prasanna, How are things going? Have you tried as my above suggestion that directory set '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)' as the source path on the Azure file copy task? Is is helpful to you? If you also have other artifacts need to copy to the Azure blob, you can create a directory in the Workspace on the agent machine, and copy all the artifacts (include the artifacts in '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)') into this directory, then set this directory as the the source path on the Azure file copy task. Please try it, any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Azure file copy task**](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV1/README.md) generally is used to copy files or directly from the agent machine to a Azure blob or Azure VMs.

The source files or directly you want to copy must be existing on the agent machine when executing this task.

In the steps you shared, I do not see any step to create the directory "**$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop**" on the agent machine, and copy or generate the artifacts into this directory. This directory is not automatically generated by default during the pipeline run. So, this directory is not existing.

> **NOTE:** the [**Publish Build Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) will not generate the **drop** folder into **$(Pipeline.Workspace)** on the agent machine. It just generates the **drop** folder on the details page of each pipeline run to store the published artifacts of the run.
> [image]

In your case, I noticed that you have copy the build artifacts into the **$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)** directory on the agent machine. If you want to copy the build artifacts to the Azure blob, you can directory set the source path as **$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)** on the **Azure file copy task**.